# SharePoint 2013 LDS Groups permissions not working

Tags: 2013, permissions, groups, ad-lds

I set up LDS Authentication correctly. LDS users can login in without problems. In people picker, I can see lds users and groups, but when I set permissions on groups, they're not effective ... I can't understand why.

The three web.config are configured correctly. I can't find what I miss. I try to craete OU for groups, didn't work (I was still able to select it from people picker), or Container.
Should I use CN=Roles to create groups ?

FYI, I follow those 3 links :
-   http://blogs.developpeur.org/anouvel/archive/2010/09/12/sharepoint-2010-configuration-de-l-authentification-par-formulaire-avec-annuaire-ad-lds-partie-3-configuration-de-l-authentification-par-formulaire.aspx
-   http://thesharepointfarm.com/2012/01/sharepoint-2010-and-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-better-together/
-   http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/ad-lds-sharepoint-and-forms-based-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this same issue and fixed it, here's how.  After following many of the same templates that you did from blogs and tutorials to obtain the code for the web.config files, finally when checking this older page I saw that the LDAPROLE provider should also have a few more attributes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd897500(v=office.12).aspx

These are the two that are missing from the LDAPROLE provider code block in most of the examples above.  Once I added them, I had full functionality from my LDAP groups in Sharepoint.

useUserDNAttribute="true"
userContainer="cn=users,dc=contoso,dc=com"

Comment: you were right. I do not have the "userContainer" node in the LDAP Role code block (while it's present in the Membership code block). So I will do some tests, and come back if this works. Thanks @brichBOISE for your answer.

Comment: Ok, by adding the "userContainer" attribute, I'm now able to set permissions on LDAP Group. Thanks.
Now, the point is : I can't play with OU or Container to put my users wherever I want ... Else group's permissions are not effective ...

Comment: EDIT: Everything is working fine (that was just a minor bug).

Comment: I would add another little question : Is it possible to add some Roles in the LDAP? I mean : What if I want to delegate the user creation and reset password right to people ? And I want this people to access the OU/Container or w/e only. So they access the customer they are in charge with, and manage his users/passwords.